# Favicon doesn't show on social media link previews

Tags: html, favicon, head

I have a favicon added in my HTML this way `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`.

The favicon shows when opened on web browsers normally, but when I paste the website's link on social media links like Slack or WhatsApp, the favicon isn't part of the preview.

What I want to achieve:

[image: example of what I want to achieve]

What I have:

[image: what I have]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your `href=""` is not absolute - could that be an issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "absolute"? @Dai

Comment: `href="/favicon.ico"` is an absolute path, while `href="favicon.ico"` is a relative path. The difference matters depending on what URI path your HTML page/documented is being served from.

Comment: it didn't work @Dai

Comment: @Dai So I figured out my favicon wasn't showing because of the size/resolution. I adjusted it using favicon.io and it worked. Thanks for your help.